# How to increment counter with button click in Razor pages

Tags: jquery, razor-pages

Hello I try to implement Jquery to my Razor page
First one work. But I cannot found root cause why after foreach it not work.

My Html:

```
    @foreach(var item in Model.ErrorList)
    {
        <input  type="button" id=@item.ErrorListID value=@item.ErrorName />
        <input type="text" name="Tb+@item.ErrorListID" id="Tb+@item.ErrorListID" value="0" />

    }
```

Working script:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
             //var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                $('#AddButton').click( function() {
                    var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                    counter++ ;
                    $('#TextBox').val(counter);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And JQ for all buttons. There must be some mistake:-(

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ErrorList)
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
        $('#@item.ErrorListID').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Tb+@item.ErrorListID').val();
            counter++ ;
            $('#Tb+@item.ErrorListID').val(counter);
        });
    });
    </script>
}
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end of the last code snippet.

Comment: I don't use Razor, but maybe it doesn't substitute `@item` inside strings.

Comment: So try `$('#Tb' + @item.ErrorListID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class on the buttons, you would walk around that issue.

From each button click, you can target the "next" `input`.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ErrorList)
{
    <input type="button" class="incrementer" id=@item.ErrorListID value=@item.ErrorName />
    <input type="text" name="Tb+@item.ErrorListID" id="Tb+@item.ErrorListID" value="0" />
}
```

And then, you only need one event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.incrementer').click( function() {
        let nextInput = $(this).next("input")
        let count = parseInt(nextInput.val()) + 1
        nextInput.val(count)
    });
});
```

Comment: THX you help me a lot